# How to redirect a Heroku subdomain to an external VPS?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, heroku, namecheap

I have the following setup:

- Wordpress blog hosted on a VPS (ip: `123.44.55.66`)
- Heroku app live at (`my-app.heroku.com`)
- Domain name bought from Namecheap (`www.my-app.com`)
- Heroku domain is already setup so it correctly shows up on `www.my-app.com`

I want to be able to redirect `blog.my-app.com` to my VPS (hiding the IP and showing as `blog.my-app.com`) but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried setting the `A` record of my NameCheap DNS to point to `123.44.55.66` but that doesn't seem to work.

What additional configuration am I missing?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: It's not redirecting anywhere. Also, running `host blog.my-app.com` returns a `Host blog.my-app.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Here is the final configuration:

**Heroku**
Add a new domain

- Domain name: `blog.my-app.com`
- DNS target: `blog.my-app.com.herokudns.com`

**NameCheap DNS**
First setup an `A` record:

- Type: `A`
- Host: `blog`
- Value: `123.44.55.66`
- TTL: `Automatic`

Now setup a `URL Redirect Record`

- Type: `URL Redirect Record`
- Host: `@`
- Value: `http://blog.my-app.com`

**WordPress** Settings (in your VPN)

- WordPress Address (URL): `http://blog.my-app.com`
- Site Address (URL): `http://blog.my-app.com`